# Something other than snapToPoint is controlling layout in UISnapBehavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uisnapbehavior

I am new to animation and struggling to understand why UIAnimation and UISnapBehavior appear to shift UIButtons off-centre. Clearly there is something controlling layout besides what is in my code. Maybe someone can tell me what I'm missing.

Originally my ViewController had five UIButtons placed programmatically (i.e. without a XIB file) on the circumference of the circle as shown in Figure A. In revising my app I introduced snap animation to move UIButtons into position from a centre point. Figure B shows the centre point where animation starts. Figure C shows the five UIButtons which are displaced after animation finishes even though CGPoints used for `snapToPoint:` are exactly the same as CGPoints used to place UIButtons.

[image]

When I clicked in the black rectangular area at the bottom of the screen I noticed a message in the logged report `unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent` which included the size properties of frame. This suggested that frames or bounds may be a reason for UIButtons being off centre following animation.

Here is the latest version of the code I used to demonstrate what happens. I believe it is correct even if it wouldn't win any prizes in an Object-Oriented beauty contest :-)

Firstly, the five buttons without animation shown in Figure A.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSLog(@"load GlobalView");

CGRect dot1 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 38.0f,  .origin.y = 263.0f, .size.width = 80.0f, .size.height = 80.0f,};
CGRect dot2 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 207.0f, .origin.y = 263.0f, .size.width = 80.0f, .size.height = 80.0f,};
CGRect dot3 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 123.0f, .origin.y = 320.0f, .size.width = 80.0f, .size.height = 80.0f,};
CGRect dot4 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 170.0f, .origin.y = 167.0f, .size.width = 80.0f, .size.height = 80.0f,};
CGRect dot5 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 70.0f,  .origin.y = 167.0f, .size.width = 80.0f, .size.height = 80.0f,};
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT. The following lines of code redefine `origin` so `CGRect` is centred on the circumference of the circle. They replace the lines above which define `origin` as the top left apex of  `CGRect`. Animation now places UIButtons according to the layout shown in Figure A.

```
 */

float width  = 80.0f;
float height = 80.0f;

CGRect dot1 = (CGRect) { .origin.x =  38.0f + width/2, .origin.y = 263.0f + width/2, width, height};
CGRect dot2 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 207.0f + width/2, .origin.y = 263.0f + width/2, width, height};
CGRect dot3 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 123.0f + width/2, .origin.y = 320.0f + width/2, width, height};
CGRect dot4 = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 170.0f + width/2, .origin.y = 167.0f + width/2, width, height};
CGRect dot5 = (CGRect) { .origin.x =  70.0f + width/2, .origin.y = 167.0f + width/2, width, height};
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
// Insert global rings
UIView *ringView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 178.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
UIImage *ringImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GlobalRings.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ringImage];
imageView.frame = ringView.bounds;  // frame imageView in ringView and fill ringView
[ringView addSubview:imageView];    // add the imageview to the superview
[self.view addSubview:ringView];    //add the view to the main view

// place 5 UIButtons

UIButton *navigationButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
navigationButton1.frame = CGRectMake(38.0, 263.0, 80.0, 80.0);
[navigationButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dot1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navigationButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToVenue1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *navigationButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
navigationButton2.frame = CGRectMake(207.0, 263.0, 80.0, 80.0);
[navigationButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dot2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navigationButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToVenue2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *navigationButton3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton3 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
navigationButton3.frame = CGRectMake(123.0, 320.0, 80.0, 80.0);
[navigationButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dot3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navigationButton3 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToVenue3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *navigationButton4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton4 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
navigationButton4.frame = CGRectMake(170.0, 167.0, 80.0, 80.0);
[navigationButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dot4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navigationButton4 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToVenue4) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *navigationButton5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton5 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
navigationButton5.frame = CGRectMake(70.0, 167.0, 80.0, 80.0);
[navigationButton5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dot5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navigationButton5 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToVenue5) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:navigationButton1];
[self.view addSubview:navigationButton2];
[self.view addSubview:navigationButton3];
[self.view addSubview:navigationButton4];
[self.view addSubview:navigationButton5];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Then to place the five UIButtons at the centre before the animation starts I aligned each UIButton with the frame centre by adding

```
CGRect preSnap = (CGRect) { .origin.x = 120.0f, .origin.y = 240.0f, .size.width = 80.0f, .size.height = 80.0f,};
```

and then changing each button frame (below) to set the starting point for the animation

```
navigationButton1.frame = preSnap;
navigationButton2.frame = preSnap;
navigationButton3.frame = preSnap;
navigationButton4.frame = preSnap;
navigationButton5.frame = preSnap;
```

Then I added `UISnapBehaviour` to the animation by inserting pointers immediately after `viewDidLoad`

```
UIDynamicAnimator* _animator1;
UIDynamicAnimator* _animator2;
UIDynamicAnimator* _animator3;
UIDynamicAnimator* _animator4;
UIDynamicAnimator* _animator5;
UISnapBehavior* _snap1;
UISnapBehavior* _snap2;
UISnapBehavior* _snap3;
UISnapBehavior* _snap4;
UISnapBehavior* _snap5;
```

and adding `UIDynamicAnimator` and `UISnapBehavior` methods just before `[super viewDidLoad];` resulting in the `UIButton` layout shown in Figure C

```
_animator1 = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
_snap1  = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:navigationButton1 snapToPoint: dot1.origin];
[_animator1 addBehavior:_snap1];

_animator2 = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
_snap2  = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:navigationButton2 snapToPoint: dot2.origin];
[_animator2 addBehavior:_snap2];

_animator3 = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
_snap3  = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:navigationButton3 snapToPoint: dot3.origin];
[_animator3 addBehavior:_snap3];

_animator4 = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
_snap4  = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:navigationButton4 snapToPoint: dot4.origin];
```

[_animator4 addBehavior:_snap4];

```
_animator5 = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
_snap5  = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:navigationButton5 snapToPoint: dot5.origin];
[_animator5 addBehavior:_snap5];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Finally I added five methods to make sure all buttons worked

```
- (void)goToVenue1 {
NSLog(@"Button 1 worked");
}
- (void)goToVenue2 {
NSLog(@"Button 2 worked");
}
- (void)goToVenue3 {
NSLog(@"Button 3 worked");
}
- (void)goToVenue4 {
NSLog(@"Button 4 worked");
}
- (void)goToVenue5 {
NSLog(@"Button 5 worked");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. In earlier drafts the `origin` coordinates were those on the top left apex. It was necessary to redefine `origin` so `CGRect` is centred on the circumference of the circle.